# Tensorflow 1.5 on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I followed these instructions to compile tensorflow:
https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md

I pulled the newest bazel (0.9.0)from github and compiled it successfully. After that I pulled the newest tensorflow (1.5.0) from github then applied this command

```
grep -Rl 'lib64' | xargs sed -i 's/lib64/lib/g'
```

I skipped the editing of `tensorflow/workspace.bzl`. Then I ran the configuration script and provided the paths for python 3.5. Compilation was after one night successful with following command from tutorial:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Then I builded the package:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

Then the installation in python also worked without errors:

```
sudo pip3 install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.5.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

But then when I start python3 from my home directory and try to import tensorflow with: `import tensorflow as tf` following error appears:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looking for ConcatCPU defined here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/core/kernels/concat_lib_cpu.cc#L51

```
undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow9ConcatCPUINS_8bfloat16EEEvPNS_10DeviceBaseERKSt6vectorISt10unique_ptrINS_6TTypesIT_Li2EiE11ConstMatrixESt14default_deleteIS9_EESaISC_EEPNS8_6MatrixE
```

So there may be something wrong with your bazelrc.

You have multiple options:

1) Dig in your bazelrc and check that concat_lib_cpu.cc is being compiled, check that the linker sees it, etc.

2) RECOMMENDED - Simply download the package from ci.tensorflow.org and install:

Python 3: http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-python3/lastSuccessfulBuild/

Python 2: http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/lastSuccessfulBuild/

3) Use Tensorflow Lite if you can, remember RPIs are limitted.

Good luck.